# Get selected value from UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

As my title said that how can i get selected value from `UIPickerView`?
is it following delegate method use for achieve it or not suggest me?

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get selected value from `UIPickerView` by

```
NSString *selValue = [myArrayList objectAtIndex:[_myPickerView selectedRowInComponent:N]] // Here "N" is component like 0 or whatever.
NSLog (@"%@", selValue);
```